# Getting the last 25 rows of a table using eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am currently transitioning my website to laravel and I am having problems turning the following SQL into eloquent:

```
(SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `lobby`='$lobbyid' AND `timestamp` > '1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25) order by id'
```

I have tried:

```
return DB::table('messages')
                ->select('*')
                ->where('lobby', $lobbyid)
                ->where('timestamp', '>', 1)
                ->orderby('id', 'desc')
                ->limit(25)
                ->orderby('id')
                ->get();
```

But the second `order by` simply gets ignored. As the title suggests, this query is meant to get the last 25 messages of a specific lobby chat. The sql itself works I just need help converting it to eloquent if possible.

Comment: You can only use one `order by`. In this context you would only need one anyway: The first `order by` return the records in exactly the same order as the second `order by`

Comment: This could get ugly because you may need to use a raw subquery here.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen Correct, but the first part `SELECT * FROM messages WHERE lobby='$lobbyid' AND timestamp > '1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25` actually gets the last 25 messages...the problem is that the higher id's are showing up first. The higher ID's should be last because they are the newer messages.

Comment: Ah, clear: Best to sort your results in php once you have loaded them in an object. Alternatives: Lots of code (much more then a array sort) or a view (which would be a second model, so also lots of code)

Comment: You can run your raw sql directly in laravel

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get 25 results from query and then Reorder array in php

```
$result = DB::table('messages')
                ->select('*')
                ->where('lobby', $lobbyid)
                ->where('timestamp', '>', 1)
                ->orderby('id', 'desc')
                ->limit(25)
                ->get();
```

Reorder array:

```
$result= array_sort($result , 'id', SORT_ASC);

function array_sort($array, $on, $order=SORT_ASC){

    $new_array = array();
    $sortable_array = array();

    if (count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                    if ($k2 == $on) {
                        $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
            }
        }

        switch ($order) {
            case SORT_ASC:
                asort($sortable_array);
                break;
            case SORT_DESC:
                arsort($sortable_array);
                break;
        }

        foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
            $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
    }

    return $new_array;
}
```

Or use will use Laravel Raw query:

```
 DB::raw((SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `lobby`='$lobbyid' AND `timestamp` > '1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25) order by id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this with Eloquent query:

```
Message::where('lobby', $lobbyid)
       ->where('timestamp', '>', 1)
       ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
       ->take(25)
       ->get();
```

**Note**: Message is Model name.